# Lazy loading android ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-lazyloading

I'm using Fedor's adapter and imageloader to lazy load images into an expandablelistview. ([Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)) It works perfectly but with one problem. An image will only display when the imageview (in the listview row) goes off screen and then comes back on (via scrolling or collapsing and expanding the listview group.) Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `invalidate()` on the ImageView, or `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, after assigning the Drawable or Bitmap.